# Составной sql-запрос для выбора слов из файлов

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, запрос

Есть база данных Postgres, которая содержит следующие связанные таблицы со следующими полями:

- `therms` (с полями `id` типа `integer` (первичный ключ) и `value` типа `text` (содержит слова из индексируемых файлов))
- `fs_entries` (с полями `id` типа `integer` и `value` типа `text`, где `value` содержит имена индексируемых файлов)
- `therms_occurs` (с полями `file_id` типа `integer` и `therm_id` типа `integer`, где `therm_id` внешний ключ и связано с полем `id` таблицы `therms`, а поле `file_id` внешний ключ и связано с полем `id` таблицы `fs_entries`).

Помогите составить запрос (потому что я новичок в SQL), выдающий все слова, упорядоченные по принадлежности к файлам, и сами имена файлов.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT a.value, c.value 
FROM therms a 
JOIN therms_occurs b 
ON b.threm_id = a.id 
JOIN fs_entries c 
ON b.file_id = c.id 
ORDER BY c.value, a.value
```

Comment: вкралась опечатка, надо "ON b.therm_id = a.id "